# Interrupt handler and virtual memory

Tags: cpu, interrupt, virtual-memory, interrupt-handling

Does interrupt handler is running like user programs in the meaning of virtual memory (TLB miss - load page descriptor) or there are on any CPU difference solution?

Answer (score 1):

The interrupt service routine (ISR) is going to execute in kernel mode.  The jump table that the processor uses to figure out what routine to run on the interrupt itself cannot be swapped out, because the page fault handler would also be found there.  I don't know for sure what would happen if the handler address pointed to an unmapped region of memory.  Virtual memory can be supported in kernel mode, at least on x86.  Maybe some architectures could handle an access fault for an ISR address, but an OS would never implement that, because the latency for entering the ISR would be totally unacceptable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Oh, sorry for my English, you probably don't understand the question. I mean that interrupt handler suffers with delay connected with translation virtual address to physical (TLB misses for example). It wouldn't be better to do by this - memory model is divided in rate for example 1:3, where 1/4 of memory is unmapped (exactly for OS requirements). By me, OS doesn't require translation virtual addresses to physical when is managing it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can go without page tables.  Or you can have a single level page table where one top-level entry covers all of RAM.  In either case, you would (essentially) never incur the overhead of a TLB miss.  Note that TLB misses don't generally constitute much overhead.  The associativity is high, and every entry corresponds to at least 4KB of memory, so the spatial and temporal locality are high.  The TLB is searched in parallel to accessing the cache, so it doesn't incur any overhead on a hit.